# Proving a limit summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k}{k^2+n^2} = \frac{1}{2}\, \log 5$$

How would you prove this? I understand limits, but summations not so much. 
Would I need to take the derivative of the summation first, then evaluate the limit of that?

Comment: This is a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k}{k^2 + n^2} = \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k = 1}^{2n} \frac{\frac{k}{2n}}{\left(\frac{k}{2n}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{4}}$$

we see that your sum is a Riemann sum for the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x^2 + 1/4}$ over the interval $[0,1]$. So the limit is

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^2 + 1/4}\, dx$$

Using a $u$-sub $u = x^2 + 1/4$, you can show that integral evaluates to $\dfrac{\log 5}{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain how you found the second summation? I understand everything else except that part,

Comment: he divided everything the top by $2n$ and the bottom by $4n^2$. That's why the additional $1/2n$ outside balances the top and makes an equality

Comment: @kobe How did you know this was a riemann sum for that function?

Comment: @A.Mercs in the equation above, the right-hand side can be written $\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k = 1}^n f(\frac{k}{2n})$ for some function $f$, which we see by inspection is $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1/4}$.